# Filtering a CoreData FetchRequest

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode4, nsfetchrequest

I am having a brain meltdown trying to filter a fetchRequest.

I'm able to get the full details of every record of the entity, but I only want the details on the record at the current indexPath.

This is where my code is at present:

```
-(void) fetchStuff {

    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__); 
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];      
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *woodgie = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WidgetEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:woodgie];

    NSArray *fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


    fetchedObjects = [fetchResults objectAtIndex:selectedRow];


    NSLog(@"selectedRow: %i", selectedRow);  //0

    NSLog(@"fetchedObjects: %@", fetchedObjects);



     for (WidgetEntity *wigglies in fetchedObjects  ) {

         NSSet *peopleSet = [wigglies valueForKey:@"people"];    
         for (id person in peopleSet) {          
             personName = [person valueForKey:@"name"];
             NSLog(@"name = %@", personName);
         }
         NSSet *keywordSet = [wigglies valueForKey:@"keyword"];  
         for (id keyWord in keywordSet) {
              keywordName = [keyWord valueForKey:@"word"];
             NSLog(@"Keyword = %@", keywordName);

.....
}
```

I get an exception at this line " for (WidgetEntity *wigglies in fetchedObjects  ) {"
(countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance)..

but the truth is - I'm guessing how to filter the data.

Any help / pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Set breakpoint before that line, and print the class of the object with `po [fetchedRecord class]` in debug console.

Comment: Thanks - that shows "WidgetEntity"

Comment: Oh, so you tried to enumerate a single object rather than an array. See the line `fetchedRecord = [fetchResults objectAtIndex:selectedRow]`.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting all of the records in the entity, but I only want the current one.. How do I do that?

Comment: You should know the answer. If you want the record for the selected row, just process the single `fetchedRecord`. If you want to enumerate through all the results, use `for`-`in` loop on `fetchedResults`, not `fetchedRecord`.

Comment: But that is what I was doing, and I got the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about fetching the record in the *"row that has been selected"* - this suggests that you have **already** fetched the records and are displaying them, presumably in a table view.

In that case there is no need to re-fetch the entities, simply use the object from the appropriate index in your data source array or your fetched results controller.

Comment: You are probably right, and i'm over thinking it. I can't get my head around where to pick up the object. I'm using sensible cocoa which makes asking for help a little more difficult.

Comment: Never heard of that until just now. I had a quick look at the documentation, I think you just need to look at whatever you've supplied for the data source array(s) - or ask the sensible cocoa people, and get your money's worth from them!

Comment: I got it and you were right on. I had the values and just needed to get the correct index. It works just fine. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) fetchStuff {

    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__); 
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];      
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *woodgie = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WidgetEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:woodgie];

    NSArray *fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


    fetchedRecord = [fetchResults objectAtIndex:selectedRow];


    NSLog(@"selectedRow: %i", selectedRow);  //0

    NSLog(@"fetchedRecord: %@", fetchedRecord); // this looks ok
```

Check the following **two lines** carefully.

```
     //for (WidgetEntity *wigglies in fetchResults  ) { // crash out here
     WidgetEntity *wigglies = fetchedRecord;

         NSSet *peopleSet = [wigglies valueForKey:@"people"];    
         for (id person in peopleSet) {          
             personName = [person valueForKey:@"name"];
             NSLog(@"name = %@", personName);
         }
         NSSet *keywordSet = [wigglies valueForKey:@"keyword"];  
         for (id keyWord in keywordSet) {
              keywordName = [keyWord valueForKey:@"word"];
             NSLog(@"Keyword = %@", keywordName);

.....
}
```

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your help. This doesn't crash, but it gives me all the records in the entity. I need to be able to fetch the one in the row that was selected.

Comment: OK. I'm an idiot.. I understand.. Thanks a ton... Maybe time to stop for today :)

Comment: I answered too quickly.. I was excited.. WidgetEntity *wigglies = fetchedRecord; gives me an error - incompatible pointer types - entity and array.. What should fetchedRecord be?